Choose Which API Endpoints to Allow with Next.js
I'm using some endpoints locally to do questionable stuff I shouldn't be doing or allowing in production. As such, I would like to disallow these endpoints when I deploy things.
How do I do that with Next.js? Is it through next.config.mjs or middleware.js?

Are the endpoints implemented through directory structure?

@Codebling I'm using Next.js 14, and my API routes are inside src/app/api/<path>/route.ts. Was that what you were looking for?

You will do it using middleware, the Next.js docs Middleware page give you great examples.
Look for matchers in the config variable, this will allow you to configure behaviours for each individual route.
Alternatively, you could do something like this in your middleware.ts file:
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/path/you/want/to/filter/out")) {
    // Capture the path, but don't pass it through...
    // (Instead of doing something like (`NextResponse.next()`)
    return NextResponse.json({})
  }
}

